# why doesn't it shows no result,but shows no error

Tags: python, python-3.7

I have written a code to get a root of a function.But it doesn't show any result.neither does it shows any error:

```
import math
from math import e
#finding root of f(x)=(e**-x)-x:
#f'(x)=(-e**-x)-1
#y=x-(f(x)/f'(x))
def f(x):
    x=0
    y=x-(((e**-x)-x)/((-e**-x)-1))
    z=((y-x)/y)*100
    while z<(10**-8):
        print(f"The root is {y}")
        x=y
```

Comment: Do you actually call `f`?

Comment: I removed x=0 and then called f(x=0) and it still shows no result. I even removed the function and ran it,but it still then showed no result

Comment: Did you verify that the condition for the `while` loop is true at least once?

Comment: I only ran the loop without function.It shows no result.    How can i verify it??

Comment: By printing z, for example? You should read this: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from math import e


def f():
    x = 0
    y = x-(((e**-x)-x)/((-e**-x)-1))
    z = ((y-x)/y)*100
    print(z)
    while z < (10**-8):
        print("The root is {}".format(y))
        x = y

f()
```

The Output for Z is 100

Which Greater Than (10**-8) so while loop never works

Answer (score 0):

The initial value of `z` is 100.

Therefore, it won't satisfy the `z < (10**-8)` and won't enter the `while` loop.

However, we can use recursion to find out the desired value: `x = 0.5671432904`, while we are trying to find we need to set a maximum-iteration value, otherwise process finishes with an error.

Also, since we are going to use recursion, we don't need while loop anymore, instead we can check with if statement.

Here is my solution:

```
from math import e
# desired output: x=0.5671432904
max_iter = 950
count = 0
result = -1


def f(x):
    global count, result
    count += 1
    if count < max_iter:
        y = x-(((e**-x)-x)/((-e**-x)-1))
        z = ((y-x)/y)*100
        if z < (10**8):
            x = y
            result = x
            f(x)


f(0)
print("The root is {:.10f}".format(result))
```

Output:

```
The root is 0.5671432904
```